How to set the brush falloff for all brushes in a single step?
Problem
I have imported 100 brushes to work with, each has a different individual setup.
Question
Is there a way to set the Falloff to "Smoother" on each of them in a single step?
Or do I have to set the Falloff one after the other? Currently I change the Falloff to Smoother on the brush I'm working with and when I switch the brush to another, then the Falloff of that new selected brush is being used instead of "Smoother".
Or is there another way, like e. g. having a single brush and just change the texture? In the set I'm working with only the textures matter.

